# Navigation Bar retains class when scrolling despite having a function to remove the class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to create a navigation bar that sticks when you scroll past. I've gotten to the point where the bar will stick when I scroll past, but when I scroll back to the top the navbar is still sticking. I've been able to troubleshoot to realize that the navbar.offsetTop is being set to 0 when scrolling past, which causes the class "sticky" to never be removed. How can I fix this so that the navbar retains its original offset while being "stuck" to the top of the page?

**HTML**

```
    <div style="height: 40px">
    <ul class="navbar" id="navbar">
        <a class="navbutton left" href="about.html"><b>About</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton left" href="Games.html"><b>Games</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton left" href="#"><b>Btn 1</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton left" href="#"><b>Btn 2</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton left" href="#"><b>Btn 3</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton left" href="#"><b>Btn 4</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton" href="#" style="float: right"><b>Btn 5</b></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Monaco;
    background-color: white;
    color: #f0dcca;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
.navbutton {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* padding: length|initial|inherit; */
    padding: 10px 12px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.navbutton:hover {
    background-color: #f0dcca;
    color: black;
}
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}
.sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function stickyNav() {
    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var navTop = navbar.offsetTop;

console.log('navTop = ' + navTop);
console.log('scrollY = ' + window.scrollY);

    if (window.scrollY >= navTop) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    }
    else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', stickyNav);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the function definition of stickyNav.

What I'm seeing is stickyNav function is registered as a callback for the scroll event. But the variables navbar and navTop are inside the function which is assigning values to them every time you scroll. And navTop is getting assigned 0 every time. And the sticky class is never removed.

Try avoiding reassigning values. This worked for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Monaco;
        background-color: white;
        color: #f0dcca;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        height: 1000px;
      }

      .navbar {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
      }

      .navbutton {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        /* padding: length|initial|inherit; */
        padding: 10px 12px;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
      }

      .navbutton:hover {
        background-color: #f0dcca;
        color: black;
      }

      .sticky {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .content {
        padding: 16px;
      }

      .sticky+.content {
        padding-top: 60px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function stickyNav() {
        var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
        var navTop = navbar.offsetTop;

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
          console.log('navTop = ' + navTop);
          console.log('scrollY = ' + window.scrollY);
          if (window.scrollY >= navTop) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky");
          } else {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="stickyNav()">
    <h1>dummy content</h1>
    <h1>dummy content</h1>
    <h1>dummy content</h1>
    <div style="height: 40px">
      <ul class="navbar" id="navbar">
        <a class="navbutton left" href="about.html"><b>About</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton left" href="Games.html"><b>Games</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton left" href="#"><b>Btn 1</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton left" href="#"><b>Btn 2</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton left" href="#"><b>Btn 3</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton left" href="#"><b>Btn 4</b></a>
        <a class="navbutton" href="#" style="float: right"><b>Btn 5</b></a>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: When moving the vars to outside of the function, the function doesn't work at all and console gives me an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null at scripts.js:41". A google search suggested I add "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {", but then the page fails to load all together. I also tried adding the vars and function into a script tag directly into the HTML document, but my initial problem occurs with the navbar keeping the sticky class.

Comment: Check snippet now. I edited the solution to your problem. Added onload="stickyNav()" event.

Comment: Works great! It turns out that some of my problems were also caused by chrome running a cached version of my page, so some of the updates I was making to the files weren't being pushed through. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.